# Using rowSum and subset to clean data

Tags: r, subset, rowsum

I am having trouble subsetting a large data frame. I have 5,000 observations and 60+ columns. I want to subset based on ~ 30 columns -- essentially to "drop" any observations where the sum of the values in these 30 columns of `interest == 0`. A small sample is below: I would want to get rid of UID #1 and #3.

```
UID 236.1(b) 261.5(c) 261.5(d)
 1       0        0       0 
 2       2        3       0
 3       0        0       0
 4       0        0       0
```

I have tried the following code:

```
sub <- subset(df, rowSums(df[, 29:60]>0))
```

which generated the following error term:

> Error in subset.data.frame(merge_charge, rowSums(merge_charge[, 29:60] >  : 'subset' must be logical

and:

```
 test <- subset(rowSums(df[,29:60]>0))
```

Which generated the following error:

> Error in subset.default(rowSums(merge_charge[, 29:60] > 0)) : 
>     argument "subset" is missing, with no default

Any suggestions or pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: correction: sub <- subset(df, rowSums(df[, 29:60])>0). In above code position of parenthesis is wrong in your code.

Answer (score 3):

First, take a look at **subset()** function.
You can use it like this:

```
subset(data, condition)
```

So, you miss the **data** argument here.

Second, you put **(** in **rowSums** wrongly. It must be **rowSums(df[,1:2]) > 0**
Therefore, It'll be:

```
test <- subset(your_data, rowSums(your_data[,29:60])>0 )
```